# Angular : Routing with data after GET

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I currently have an Angular 2 frontend + Java backend application.

There is a form witch is composed of some search criteria.
On submit, I proceed to a search : an http get method which is returning a result (complex type).
I want to display this result on another page, using routing.

How should I process?

Can I pass some datas whithin the navigate method of router?

Any help would be appreciated. I will continue searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is using services to communicate between components.

Please check this link from angular to view how.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

You can also pass parameters to the link and read that parameter in the component that is called by the route.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So basic idea here is you want to sub,it a form and based on query want to show result in another component.

My suggestion would be to navigate to the other component using routerLink and parameter as whatever you have entered in form and in second components `ngAfterViewInit` you can query the backend so you can get the results in the second component.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Routing is not meant to pass large objects.  You can pass route parameters and query parameters, but not complex objects.

If you need to share data across components, it is recommended to use a shared instance of the service to do so.

It is recommended to use observable for shared services, though, not a requirement by any means.  An example would look like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MySharedService {
  // BehaviorSubjects start with a default value and replay the latest value to components that subscribe at any point in the lifecycle.
  //  Subject types do not start with a default value and do not replay the latest value, so if a component subscribes after it's fired, it won't receive the value.
  private someStringDataSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  someString$ = this.someStringDataSource.asObservable();


  setSomeString(newString: string) {
    this.someStringDataSource.next(newString);
  }

}



export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   sub: Subscription;

  constructor(private sharedService: MySharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to data from service
     this.sharedService.someString$.subscribe(data => //do something with data);


     //send data to service
     this.sharedService.setSomeString('newString');
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
     this.sub.unsubscribe();     
  }

}
```